# Blacklisting offensive sentences

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I've created a game meant for younger audiences and am trying to filter out profanity and offensive names

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isBanned( std::string text ) {
    std::vector bannedSent = {
        "Profanity1",
        "Profanity2",
        "Profanity3",
        "Profanity4"
    };
    for(auto &i : bannedSent) {
        if(text == i) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error talking about "template arguments", on the line with `std::vector`, what does this mean?

Comment: You forgot to specify the type the vector holds, i.e.: `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: You could easily replace the offensive text with placeholders for the purpose of this example.

Comment: I for one got a good laugh out of having something as awfully specific as "Hitler did nothing wrong" in there.

Comment: I would assume this question was just trolling, if the error hadn't been glaringly obvious.

Comment: @paddy: I dunno I think the original code demonstrated the true purpose of OP's code better. I for one am an adult and am not traumatized by words.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen It's not about whether you or I would be offended.  It's about respecting that some visitors to this site can be offended by certain language or words.

Comment: Ah, the clbuttic question again.

Comment: FWIW using a `std::vector` isn't the best for this application. Consider a `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_set`

Answer (score 7):

You need to supply template arguments to your vector.  Since you are holding strings, you need to declare it like this:

```
std::vector< std::string > bannedSent = {
   "Gosh",
   "Golly",
   "Jeepers",
   "Troll"
};
```

Comment: I will not accept this because of the "Donald Trump" comment, keep politics out of this

Comment: My apologies.  I had assumed that would be fine, given the political reference in your question.

Comment: @HasanMueed now that he has removed the reference to Donald Trump you should accept it since it is correct and solves your problem

Comment: Haha oh yes, @erip I even had to blacklist the emotions I was feeling!!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is actually *not* to specify the type. The compiler already has a decent idea, and you already knew the keyword:

```
auto bannedSent = {
    "Profanity1",
    "Profanity2",
    "Profanity3",
    "Profanity4"
};
for(auto i : bannedSent) { ...
```

Side benefit: This avoid constructing 4 `std::string` objects in each call.

Note that you used `auto& i` earlier. That's a mistake, you don't intend to change `bannedSent`.

Comment: be careful with this. bannedSet type will not be `vector<string>` but `initializer_list`

Answer (score 1):

If should be `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
bool isBanned( std::string text ) {
    std::vector<std::string> bannedSent = {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you include the C++11 tag, you can also use `any_of()`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool isBanned(const std::string & text)
{
    const std::vector<std::string> bannedSent = {
        "Profanity1",
        "Profanity2",
        "Profanity3",
        "Profanity4",
    };
    return std::any_of(bannedSent.begin(), bannedSent.end(), [text](std::string &s){return s == text; });
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `std:find`?

Comment: @Ferruccio: I suspect this is _slightly_ more efficient (or it would be, if the lambda took `s` by reference). `std::find` needs to create an iterator to the string found, but you don't need really need that. Of course, it would be more efficient to check if `text` starts with `"Profanity"` and then if it ends in a digit between 1 and 4 ;)